# CMake fills in an erroneous path - extra ../

Tags: cmake, path

I have a file structure that looks like this:

```
Projects/
  - ProjA/
    - ProbB/
      - src/
      - CMakeLists.txt
  - ProjC/
    - backend/
      - src/
        - ll/
          - os/
            -zephyr/
          - ll_driver.c
      - include/
        - ll/
          - os/
            - zephyr/
          - ll_driver.h
```

I am trying to include a piece of code written for another project (`ProjC/`) in the `ProjB/` project. The `CMakeLists.txt` for that project looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13.1)
find_package(Zephyr REQUIRED HINTS $ENV{ZEPHYR_BASE})
project(blinky-projb-test)

set(projc ../../ProjC/backend)

set(LLBC ${projc}/src/ll)
set(LLBC_Z ${projc}/src/ll/os/zephyr)

set(LLBH ${projc}/include/ll)
set(LLBH_Z ${projc}/include/ll/os/zephyr)

file(GLOB app_sources src/*.c)
file(GLOB extra_sources
  ${LLBC}/ll_driver.c)

target_sources(app PRIVATE ${app_sources} ${extra_sources})
target_include_directories(app PRIVATE
  ${LLBH}
  ${LLBH_Z}
  ${ZEPHYR_BASE}/kernel/include
  ${ZEPHYR_BASE}/arch/${ARCH}/include
  )
```

So, clearly, I am intending to include `../../ProjC/backend/...`, but the build fails. In the error message it is stated `cmake` is trying to include something else, however. It tries to do this: `-I../../../ProjC/backend/include/ll`. It seems like there's an extra `../` there, and I don't know why. I have not found anything about this issue in the documentation.

I'd appreciate it if someone can tell me why it behaves like this, or direct me to some resources where I can read more about this.

Comment: Which CMake version do you use? It could be that some versions interpret relative paths passed to command `target_include_directories` as relative to the directory declaring the target (`app`) in your case, not the directory which issues `target_include_directories` command. If unsure, always use **absolute** paths: `set(projc ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../ProjC/backend)`.

Comment: @tsyvarev I am using version `3.16.3`. If I change to absolute paths, as you describe, the issue still persists.

Comment: Note, that path in the `-I` option is interpreted relative to the **build** directory (where the compiler is invoked). This directory may differs from the one containing `CMakeLists.txt`. Please, add to the question the **exact** build output.